# VBA Excel - Class properties with array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class, properties

I am trying to create a class module in Excel VBA that has some properties that I wish to them be arrays. In the main module, I am doing some calculations to get some effective depth for some structural designs, in the module they are defined as an array of doubles - effDepth

```
Sub effectiveDepthCalculation(reinside As String, verticalSpacing As Variant, shearlink As Double, panelSpacing As Double, covers As Variant, bars As Variant, depth As Double, AreaSteel As Variant, percentminAs As Double, width As Double)

Dim calculation As clsCalculations
Set calculation = New clsCalculations
Dim effDepth(1 To 7) As Double, counter As Integer


If reinside = "External" Then effDepth(1) = depth - shearlink - covers(2) - bars(1) / 2 - panelSpacing
If reinside = "Internal" Then effDepth(1) = depth - shearlink - covers(4) - bars(1) / 2 - panelSpacing

For counter = 2 To UBound(bars)
    If bars(counter) <> 0 Then effDepth(counter) = effDepth(counter - 1) - verticalSpacing(counter - 1)
Next counter

For counter = 1 To UBound(effDepth) - 1
    effDepth(7) = effDepth(7) + (effDepth(counter) * AreaSteel(counter)) / AreaSteel(7)
Next counter

calculation.effectiveDepth = effDepth

Dim Asmin As Double

calculation.Asmin = percentminAs / 100 * width * effDepth(7)

end sub
```

In the class module, the propety is define as:

```
Private peffectiveDepth As Variant

Public Property Get effectiveDepth() As Variant
    effectiveDepth = peffectiveDepth()
End Property

Public Property Let effectiveDepth(value As Variant)
    peffectiveDepth = value
End Property
```

When debugging I see the compile error as variable not define:

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? or is it that we can't use arrays as properties in class modules? I certanily saw that we can use them as fields but not sure if they can be used as porperties either. Alternative, I don't mind changing it to collections but I am not sure on that approach either.

Thanks for the help.

Felipe

Comment: Code in the class module compiles for me. Even using your posted sub `effectiveDepthCalculation` does work.

Comment: You can certainly use arrays in Properties ... including Variant arrays as you are doing. You don't need the parenthesis at the end of the `effectiveDepth = peffectiveDepth()` line but this isn't the cause of your error. Try commenting-out the `Private peffectiveDepth As Variant` line (yes ... break your code) then do a Compile then uncomment-out the line and Compile again

Comment: @JohnM: _Try commenting-out the Private peffectiveDepth As Variant line (yes ... break your code) then do a Compile then uncomment-out the line and Compile again_ Are you saying that somehow the file/class module is broken/corrupt?

Comment: That is what I am wondering, but cannot tell without having 'hands on' ... I have experienced this before (rarely ... but more than once)

Comment: Dear both thanks for the responses. This is very odd but on my end, even if u remove the parenthesis from the get property and comment out to force fail the code and compile again. I still get an the same error. Would it have to do that in my sub the passing array is an array of doubles?

Comment: Its likely the ByVal issue for properties.  For properties  you must specify the parameters Using ByVal rather than ByRef.  The default for VBA is ByRef .  Try inserting ByVal  e.g. Property Let effectiveDepth(ByVal value As Variant).  If you had the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA installed you would have got this as a code inspection.

Comment: @freeflow To the best of my knowledge Properties parameters can be passed ByRef.  Rubberduck code inspection mentioned that we should consider changing it to ByVal if the references is value is not being changed.

Comment: @Tinman  sorry, just relating back to a bad experience a while back  I had where I could resolve an error in an indexed property until I changed to ByVal.

Comment: @freeflow VBA can be fickle.  But It's a lot better than it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that would cause the issue.   The `calculation.Asmin` is missing but the error occurs before that.  You would need to provide the complete code and sample data for someone to test it.  I recommend downloading [Mz Tools](https://www.mztools.com/v8/mztools8.aspx) and cleaning the project.  It is free to use with some limitations.

[Clean Project Mz Tools](https://www.mztools.com/v8/onlinehelp/MZTools8Help.html)

> The Clean Project feature allows you to solve some strange problems that can happen in VBA projects because of junk created internally by the VBA compiler. To solve these problems the classes, modules and userforms must be exported as text files, removed from the project and imported back to the project. This feature automates this process.